# How to `git fetch` the default branch

Tags: git

I'm writing a generic script which fetches some branches from a set of remote repositories, and I'd like it to only fetch *some* of the branches.  For most of the branches, this is easy because they're specified by name and I can just write a corresponding refspec, but I haven't found a way to fetch "the default branch".

I tried to pass to `git fetch` a refspec of the form `refs/heads/HEAD:MY/LOCAL/BRANCH` but that tells me:

> fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/HEAD

How can I specify "the default branch" in a refspec?  Currently, I just hardcode `master`, but of course that only works on those repositories which stick to this default.

Comment: It's just `HEAD`, not even `refs/HEAD`.

Comment: Duh!  I can't believe I couldn't find it in the docs nor in a web search.  Thanks, it works great.  If you make it an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `refs/heads/HEAD`

It's just `HEAD`, not even `refs/HEAD`. So the command should be

```
git fetch origin HEAD:MY/LOCAL/BRANCH
```

You can see available references using

```
git ls-remote origin
```

To see just the `HEAD`:

```
git ls-remote origin HEAD
```

See the docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions